# Responsive web design flaw zoom in issue

Tags: responsive-design

i made a website responsive but when it loads into the phone it is zoomed automatically i applied view port as well but didn't find solution.

- view port
- j query 
  these doesn't solve my problem.

any one please help to fix this out

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem as I just solved a similar problem myself.

Method 1
You can specify the amount of zoom that is applied by targeting a specific device group. try adding this to your index.html

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

This should keep your website from trying to scale with zoom.

If this does not work then try targeting specific devices with css

```
 @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
```

Try playing around with the zoom and width values to find your device range.

Method 2 
Open Firefox on your laptop or desktop and go to your site. and in the firefox options choose responsive view. Then press ctrl+shift+c and hover over your page to select the full page container. on the lower right hand side there will be a window with css. There you should find the element that is zooming in.

Also please update your question with your website

Comment: i have to add this @view port in my media query or any where in css